# android BLE write command with response, no response receive

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

i'm developping an android app that communicate with a BLE device(in kotlin).

i'm sending a command to the ble device, the device usually give the following response:
-OK(confirming the command was received and valid)
-one or multiple line of data
-Done

in `onCharacteristicWrite` i tryed to show this.value to read the response but look like it's not the way to do it. i googled a lot without lot of success.

so my question is how could i get the data from the response.the device send?

i try to call a readCharateristic without success either.

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

GATT does not have any protocol feature of a request - response transaction where both messages embed data.

For Write Request - Write Response, only the request can contain data. The response can only be empty or an error code.

For Read Request - Read Response, the request contain only what characteristic is to be read and the response contains some data or an error code.

To implement a request - response mechanism using GATT, one usually follows one of the following strategies:

1. Use Write Request or Write Without Response for the request message and Notification for the response message.
2. Use Write Request or Write Without Response for the request message. When the GATT server produces a response message, it is put in a characteristic that the client will then read using a Read Request.

The first method has lowest overhead and best throughput.

What you should do is to investigate what method your peripheral actually uses. If it sends its responses in notifications, you must enable these and implement the `onCharacteristicChanged` callback.

Comment: Thank you @Emil for your answer, i'll take a look into that, since i have no control over the device developpement, i'll the developper of the device more documentation about it!